# Difficulty with webkit box rounding corners

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am trying to implement a rounded corner to a box in my html code.
When I run the file on Chrome, I have the box and all the attribute but the corners won't round.
I am using Komodo Edit on MAC OSX Lion.
What's the solution?
Thanks

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="box">
    <p id="text"> Hello </p>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS3:

```
body {
  text-align:center;
}

#box {
display: block;
width: 500px;
margin:50px auto ;
padding:15px ;
text-align:center;
border: 1px solid blue;
background: red;
-webkit-border-radius: 25p;
 }

#text {
   font:bold 100px Century Gothic;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that it should be 25px instead of 25p.
But depending on you Chrome version, you should drop the -webkit- and just use border-radius;

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `-webkit-` on there. Just use `border-radius`.

The main problem is that you missed the x on `25px`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo

```
-webkit-border-radius: 25p;
```

Should be

```
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
```

You missed an x on the end.  For cross browser compliancey, you should really use several prefixes.

```
-moz-border-radius: 25px; /*Firefox*/
-webkit-border-radius: 25px; /*Safari/Chrome/Konqueror*/
-khtml-border-radius: 25px; /*Konqueror*/
border-radius: 25px; /*Chrome*/
```